# How can I improve these nested loops with np.sum?

Tags: python, numpy

How could I create this function in Python using `np.sum`?

[image: gupta potential]

I created this code and it works fine, but it would be faster using `np.sum` instead of two `for` loops, so I'm trying to figure out how to use `np.sum`.

My code:

```
def potential(x):
    A, XI, P, Q, R0 = parameters()
    atoms, _ = read_file_xyz()
    n_atoms = len(atoms)
    x = x.reshape(n_atoms, 3)
    U = 0
    for i in range(n_atoms):
        Ub = 0
        Ur = 0
        for j in range(n_atoms):
            if j != i:
                Ub += (XI[i, j]**2) * np.exp(-2 * Q[i, j] * ((np.sqrt((x[i, 0]-x[j, 0])**2 + (x[i, 1]-x[j, 1])**2 +(x[i, 2]-x[j, 2])**2) / R0[i, j]) - 1))
                Ur += A[i, j] * np.exp(-P[i, j] * ((np.sqrt((x[i, 0]-x[j, 0])**2 + (x[i, 1]-x[j, 1])**2 +(x[i, 2]-x[j, 2])**2) / R0[i, j]) - 1))
            else:
                pass
        U += (Ur - np.sqrt(Ub))
    return U
```

I'm trying to improve the execution time.

Comment: Most of this, I think, you can just do outside of the for loop.  `exp`, for example, will just apply over the array.

Comment: The "sum where `i != j`" bit is interesting.

Comment: The [`numpy.sum()`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-sum-in-python/) returns the sum of array elements over the specified axis. Could you expllain the `array`s in your problem? I see there are `XI`, `x`, `Q`, `R0`, `A`, `P`.

Comment: Or better yet, make the program [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Maybe you could just `np.sum` over the whole matrix, and then subtract the `np.sum` over the `np.diag`.

Comment: @dudung here [link](https://github.com/earturor/nanocluster-optimizer/blob/main/potentials/gupta.py) you can see the function paramters for these `XI`, `Q`, `R0`, `A`, `P`, the variable x is a matrix (Nx3) with the atom's position in x, y and z.

Comment: I see that `np` there is actually `autograd.numpy` which might be affecting things

Comment: @SamMason I use it to calculate the gradient and sometimes the Hessian.

Comment: Yup, but it's useful to point out as it'll likely have different performance characteristics than plain numpy.  Might also be worth profiling under https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene to see where it's spending time

Comment: based on the repo you linked to I see that you're reloading the input file twice and recalculating parameters on every call to this method which can't be helping with the speed of the `optimize` method, is that really needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I just look at the code you posted, I'd suggest trying to remove the inner loop and using Numpy's automatic broadcasting to do the same.  I notice that you're calculating euclidean distance in a very manual way, but that the nice [`distance` module from SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) doesn't seem to be supported by [`autograd`](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/tree/master/autograd/scipy).

This leaves me with the following code:

```
def potential(x):
    A, XI, P, Q, R0 = parameters()

    n_atoms = len(A)
    di = np.diag_indices(n_atoms)
    x = x.reshape(n_atoms, 3)

    # preprocess params to minimize work and remove need to special case "i == j"
    A[di] = 0.
    XI[di] = 0.
    P *= -1.
    Q *= -1.
    R0[di]= 1.

    U = 0.
    for i, xi in enumerate(x):
        dist = np.linalg.norm(xi - x, axis=1) / R0[i] - 1.
        Ub = XI[i] * np.exp(Q[i] * dist)
        Ur = A[i] * np.exp(P[i] * dist)
        U += sum(Ur) - sum(Ub)

    return U
```

As I was looking at your upstream code base, I saw you're calling this method from `optimize` which suggests you're loading data from files while doing numerical optimization which feels **very** wrong.

I'd therefore suggest refactoring to remove this repeated loading of data as well as doing parameter clean up.  Storing things in an object seems to make sense, and just have it expose methods for `potential` and the gradient.  Leaving me:

```
from autograd import elementwise_grad as egrad
import autograd.numpy as np

class GuptaPotential:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A, self.XI, self.P, self.Q, self.R0 = parameters()
        
        self.n_atoms = len(self.A)
        di = np.diag_indices(self.n_atoms)
        
        # preprocess params to minimize work and remove need to special case "i == j"
        self.A[di] = 0.
        self.XI[di] = 0.
        self.P *= -1
        self.Q *= -1
        self.R0[di] = 1.

    def potential(self, x):
        x = x.reshape(self.n_atoms, 3)
        U = 0.
        for i, xi in enumerate(x):
            dist = np.linalg.norm(xi - x, axis=1) / self.R0[i] - 1.
            U -= sum(self.XI[i] * np.exp(self.Q[i] * dist))
            U += sum(self.A[i] * np.exp(self.P[i] * dist))
        return U
    
    gradient = egrad(potential)
```

which you could use from the minimizer via:

```
gp = GuptaPotential()
sol = minimize(gp.potential, x0, method='BFGS', jac=gp.gradient, options={'gtol':1e-8, 'disp':True})
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sam , the code really improved a lot, I am impressed with its performance. I appreciate also your contribution on GitHub, I have homework to study the code as I am still a junior programmer. I am currently studying my Phd. in Nanotechnology and your contributions will be very helpful.